# Printing unicode using a formatfile

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I'm Facing a problem with trying to print a spool file that has a unicode characters (Arabic characters), [image: and I am using a formatfile instead of printfile]

```
SELECT PRTB ASSIGN TO FORMATFILE-PRFATCAP
       ORGANIZATION IS  SEQUENTIAL.
```

the thing is It's working on a machine, and it doesn't on another, and I can't figure out the configuration made to make the arabic printing works.

I've made sure that the `Graphic character set` is set to 235 and `Code page` is set to 420 [image: like this].

Is there anything else I can try to make this print file able to print unicode characters?

Comment: What is different, between anything relevant, on the machine on which it works and the machine on which it doesn't. Isn't that going to give you the answer?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I stuck with the same problem !!!

Comment: Printed on the same printer with the same device description and printer file definition?